# How to make WLAN server accessible on the internet

Tags: server, apache2, dns, dynamic-ip

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I've installed LAMP and I believe a DNS program and a mail server. Since my ISP is dynamic IP I am using noip.com's free dynamic DNS service (which I know works because the host name redirected to my router until I did port forwarding). The problem is that my server is accessible by using that host name however only on something connected to my network. (I tested it by turning my wifi off on my phone.)

I think the problem might have something to do with my apache2 settings, because when I restart the server it gives me this message:

```
Restarting web server apache2                                                
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.
```

I've added this line: `ServerName erikstagg.ddns.net` to my apache2.conf file and that got rid of that message, but it didn't help with accessing my website from the web.

I think that's all the information I can supply. I don't even know what to look up at this point.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I've added this line: ServerName erikstagg.ddns.net to my apache2.conf file and that got rid of that message but it didnt help with accessing my website from the web

Comment: I'm not sure if posting the real dyndns name is a good idea. In addition, please provide more info on your port forwarding/NAT setup. For http, you need to forward at least port 80 to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the configuration of your internet router and figure out how to do "Port Forwarding".

Outside requests - say for web pages - get to your router, it doesn't know what to do with them and just drops them. You need to tell it to forward the received requests - say to TCP port 80 - to the internal IP address of your actual server (and most likely the same port).

You also would want to make sure that your WLAN server has a static IP address within your local network.

**EDIT**

When I wrote `WLAN server has a static IP address` I meant the IP address of your server on the local network - i.e. 192.168.X.Y or 10.X.Y.Z. This address is normally handed over by the DHCP server built into your wireless router. You will need to get into the DHCP settings of your router, see what range of IP addresses it is handing over and configure a static *internal* one - on the same network - in your server.

Then you need to use the same internal static address in your port forwarding.

Comment: I already did the port forwarding like i said in the original post, and also like i said i dont have the option of a static ip, which is why i am using noip.com for the dynamic dns service

Comment: Oh i see what your saying. ill give that a shot and tell you what happens

Comment: ok, i have "reserved" my dhcp settings for my server in my router and so far the internal IP has not changed from what i port forwarded to (but it will help later) however I still cannot access via internet

Comment: it looks like my ISP is blocking incoming port 80 connections so im gunna try connecting via another port